# .so: undefined reference to 'min'

Tags: c, linux, undefined-reference, shared-libraries

My c application linked .so library. But application says

> library.so: undefined reference to 'min'

My compiler command like:

> gcc -o test.o library.so -ldl -lpthread -lm

Is there any solution? Please help me

Comment: If you were able to get your code to compile, but then when you attempt to execute the code, then your app cannot, at runtime, find the library your have linked to it. This can be fixed in 2 ways. You can either add the location of the library to library cache by configuring /etc/ld.so.conf adding information you place in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/. Alternately you can use `rpath` information to include the location of your library in the executable header.

Comment: In this case the library is found, but that library includes a symbol that does not exist ('min'). Either fix the library to link against the location where min can be found (or implement the function), or if that is not possible, provide a min() on your own (or link against the library it exists in, if any).

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass -library to gcc instead of library.so ,also provide library.so's location

```
gcc -L/path/to/library.so -o test.o -llibrary -ldl -lpthread -lm
```

Comment: I think it is `-lrary` instead `-llibrary`!